# Double Right-Click Mouse Function Shortcut to "Select All" Text?

Tags: text-editing, mouse-click

Is there a way to extend right-click function on mouse to 2 clicks, which would allow all text selection similar to "CTRL+A" on a keyboard?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but a triple left click selects the current block of text, if it can help.